# qooxdoo mobile : EXPERIMENTAL – NOT READY FOR PRODUCTION

Tags: qooxdoo

when looking at the qooxdoo api docs, i see some mobile classes have "EXPERIMENTAL – NOT READY FOR PRODUCTION" in their description.

i would like to know what this means. i would assume it means "do not use for a live application as it is incomplete and/or has not been tested completely". that would seem the case, as the mobile showcase has a few bugs. but i have read many cases of people using the mobile widgets in production environments, which leaves me confused.

so, are the mobile widgets fit for use? and, if not, when will they be?

Answer (score 2):

It's not that they're unfit for use.  It's that they have not been *proven* to be fit for use.  They might work just fine and suit your needs perfectly.  (And, if you're seeing them in use in the wild, that may very well be the case for some people.)

Rather than "do not use" I'd say it means "use at your own risk, we make no guarantees."